# Minimizing SSH overhead for remote command

Tags: linux, networking, ssh

My question is relatively simple. I'm thinking of using the developer SIM card from Hologram.io to remotely run commands on a server using SSH with `ssh myserver.mydomain.tld somecommand`. Since the monthly data cap is very low (1MB/month), I am trying to optimize each command as much as possible. I thought about using compression, but I don't think the improvement would really be worth it given the small amount of data being transferred. However, on such a small payload, the overhead introduced by TCP packets and ACKs is becoming significant.

Can you think of ways that I can improve efficiency for this system and save bandwidth? I'm also open to other ideas of protocols that I could use beside SSH.